# Automatically remove all music from mp3 talk show

Tags: windows-vista, audio, mp3, processing

Is there a tool that can automatically remove the music sections of a given mp3 file so only the talking part is left? This would create a better listening experience when listening to the file on my portable mp3 player.

Currently I'm doing the task manually by looking for 'dense' regions using Audacity, but this is very cumbersome for large files.

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: I found a podcast version of the radio show without music, so I don't need the tool anymore. Thanks to all who provides answeres.

Comment: Good question, but I really doubt something like this exists, unfortunately. It would be awesome, though!

Comment: I guess you could ask what aurally constitutes music? YouTube's music copyright filter identifies and removes copyrighted music (although completely blanks the audio track of an upload - rather than remove just the music segments).  I've browsed through the YouTube API documentation and sadly this audio tool they use seems to be for internal use only.  https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe there's an automatic way of achieving what you're looking for but I think you need to experiment with the High Pass and Low Pass Filters to extract the voice part of your mp3.

Even then that would probably extract the vocals (if there are any) from the music part.

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately, this seems to be too complicated. I think I will just split the files into one minute chunks and use the skip button.

Comment: my pleasure, I think that's the best way to go

Answer (score -1):

Could you try these programs and please report back to us :)

http://www.izotope.com/products/audio/msc/

http://www.elevayta.net/product13.htm

Comment: Had a quick look at the descriptions. These are way to complicated. 
Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Deniz: no one has to report back to us.